How to access ADF(Auto Document Feeder) with the WIA utility
I am trying to access image scanner for multiple document scanning from a python application. For this I am using WIA Scanner.
This works fine for one page but I want to use it for bunch of papers fed through ADF. I cant figure out how to do that. I looked into the source code but I could not see any reference to source of paper(I am not a VB coder so I may have missed). Source code can be found here.
Is it even possible to use ADF using this utility ? In windows fax and scan I can see this option.
